# How to define primary key for a column by Fluent api when my mapped file is in a separate class library?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 3 class libraries, one for my `Context` class, one for `Domain` classes and one for my fluent ApI (it's name is `Mapped`), and I want to define the primary key in `Mapped` library for my `Domain` classes, but I can't find `haskey()`!! Is there any solution?

Note: I install package for `Mapped` library too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's looks like DDD.
take a look at this sample:

*Your Domain Library: (Models)*

```
public class User
{
     public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

*Your Data Library: (Mapping)*

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.UserId);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.UserName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(256);
}
```

*Other Library: (Context)*

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    { 
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
    }
}
```

just consider that context library should have reference of **Models** and **Mapping**.